# R, Shiny Setting DataTable ID

Tags: r, datatable, shiny

I have created a large number of data tables using mapply, however, I need to access the data tables in a following step. R assigns random IDs to these tables if the user does not specify the IDs. Here is an example of what I would like to do:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  h2("Last clicked:"),
  verbatimTextOutput("last_clicked"),
  actionButton("reset", "Reset clicked value"),
  h2("Datatable:"),
  DT::dataTableOutput("dt")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  # the last clicke value
  output$last_clicked <- renderPrint({
    str(last())
  })

  output$dt <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(head(mtcars, 2), elementId = "DT_Test")
  })

  observeEvent(input$dt_cell_clicked, {
    validate(need(length(input$dt_cell_clicked) > 0, ''))
    print("You clicked something!")
  })

  myProxy = DT::dataTableProxy('dt')
  last = reactiveVal(NULL)

  observe({
    last(input$dt_cell_clicked)
  })

  observeEvent(input$reset, {
    DT::selectRows(myProxy, NULL)
    last(NULL)
    output$dt <- DT::renderDataTable({    
      DT::datatable(head(mtcars, 2))      
    })                                    
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

If I look at the html, the elementID did not change to what I wanted, in fact, R gives the warning:

```
Warning in origRenderFunc() :
  Ignoring explicitly provided widget ID "DT_Test"; Shiny doesn't use them
```

Answer (score 0):

Even after the call, still not sure what you are trying to do. 
But if you have a list of datatables and you want to access them, it works rather well like this:

```
library(shiny)
library(purrr)

ui <- fluidPage(
  h2("Last clicked:"),
  verbatimTextOutput("last_clicked"),
  h2("elementId values"),
  verbatimTextOutput("elementId_values"),
  actionButton("reset", "Reset clicked value"),
  h2("Datatable:"),
  DT::dataTableOutput("dt")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  # the last clicke value
  output$last_clicked <- renderPrint({
    str(last())
  })

  table <- DT::datatable(head(mtcars, 2), elementId = "DT_Test")
  table2 <- DT::datatable(tail(mtcars, 1), elementId = "DT_Test2")

  list_of_data_tables <- list(table, table2)
  element_ids <- purrr::map(list_of_data_tables, "elementId")

  output$elementId_values <- renderPrint({
    element_ids
  })

  output$dt <- DT::renderDataTable({
    list_of_data_tables[[which(element_ids == "DT_Test2")]]
  })


  observeEvent(input$dt_cell_clicked, {
    validate(need(length(input$dt_cell_clicked) > 0, ''))
    print("You clicked something!")
  })

  myProxy = DT::dataTableProxy('dt')
  last = reactiveVal(NULL)

  observe({
    last(input$dt_cell_clicked)
  })

  observeEvent(input$reset, {
    DT::selectRows(myProxy, NULL)
    last(NULL)
    output$dt <- DT::renderDataTable({    
      DT::datatable(head(mtcars, 2))      
    })                                    
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for... If you look at the HTML, you will see that the id of the datatbale is still dt. It didn't change at all.